# .htaccess - localhost vs server

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have .htacces like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php

Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule articles/(.*)-(.*) articles.php?$2=$1
RewriteRule download/(.*) download.php?q=$1

#add extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Now, my problem is: on localhost it works fine, but on server (mod_rewrite is enabled, checked), it throws 500 error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your complete .htaccess like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^articles/([^-]+)-(.*)$ articles.php?$2=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*)$ download.php?q=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Watch your apache error log. You'll notice rewrites with an increasing amount of `.php`. The problem is that if the file does not exist, it will keep adding `.php` until it errors out with 'too many internal rewrites'. You'll need to exclude all cases where there is already a `.php` extension in the request:

```
#add extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

To make your last rule work correctly on the other rules, you'll need the `[L]` flag to your other rules too. This will make apache go through your `.htaccess` again with the correct information in the variables.

```
RewriteRule articles/(.*)-(.*) articles.php?$2=$1 [L]
RewriteRule download/(.*) download.php?q=$1 [L]
```